# Understanding this C bitwise AND

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am not very familiar with C but trying to understand some C code.

This is the line in github:

https://github.com/hrvach/espple/blob/f968696504ded76619e06b7a1be83a6c07eaab75/user/generate_video.c#L94

Here is the same line copied in to this post for context:

```
/* 8 banks (one for each char line) of 192 bytes contain character definitions. 
Each character is pre-encoded to optimize performance. */
uint32_t *character_row = &Signetics_2513_Modulated_Video_ROM[(current_pixel_line & 0b111) * 192];
```

What I understand to be happening is that there is a C array that represents a bitmap font, contained within this file:

https://github.com/hrvach/espple/blob/master/user/signetics_video_rom.h

I had expected the line of code above to be returning a pointer to one of 8 memory locations, representing the start of each bank of pixels within that array.

I am having trouble understanding this which is extracted from the line of code above:

```
(current_pixel_line & 0b111) * 192
```

I had expected that this code would produce one of 8 values (the 8 banks referred to in the comment above).  Instead it seems to return a set of values that I don't understand.

current_pixel_line is:

```
int current_pixel_line;
```

I understand current_pixel_line to have a range of 0 to 191. (these are the rows of pixels going down a screen - i.e. a vertical resolution of 192 pixels).

But when I calculate out this function for each of 0 to 191, the values make no sense to me. Here are the calculations:

```
1st column is current_pixel_line (0 - 191)
2nd column is the decimal equivalent of 0b111
3rd column is a bitwise AND of column 1 and column 2, multiplied by 192.

0   45329   0
1   45329   192
2   45329   0
3   45329   192
4   45329   0
5   45329   192
6   45329   0
7   45329   192
8   45329   0
9   45329   192
10  45329   0
11  45329   192
12  45329   0
13  45329   192
14  45329   0
15  45329   192
16  45329   3072
17  45329   3264
18  45329   3072
19  45329   3264
20  45329   3072
21  45329   3264
22  45329   3072
23  45329   3264
24  45329   3072
25  45329   3264
26  45329   3072
27  45329   3264
28  45329   3072
29  45329   3264
30  45329   3072
31  45329   3264
32  45329   0
33  45329   192
34  45329   0
35  45329   192
36  45329   0
37  45329   192
38  45329   0
39  45329   192
40  45329   0
41  45329   192
42  45329   0
43  45329   192
44  45329   0
45  45329   192
46  45329   0
47  45329   192
48  45329   3072
49  45329   3264
50  45329   3072
51  45329   3264
52  45329   3072
53  45329   3264
54  45329   3072
55  45329   3264
56  45329   3072
57  45329   3264
58  45329   3072
59  45329   3264
60  45329   3072
61  45329   3264
62  45329   3072
63  45329   3264
64  45329   0
65  45329   192
66  45329   0
67  45329   192
68  45329   0
69  45329   192
70  45329   0
71  45329   192
72  45329   0
73  45329   192
74  45329   0
75  45329   192
76  45329   0
77  45329   192
78  45329   0
79  45329   192
80  45329   3072
81  45329   3264
82  45329   3072
83  45329   3264
84  45329   3072
85  45329   3264
86  45329   3072
87  45329   3264
88  45329   3072
89  45329   3264
90  45329   3072
91  45329   3264
92  45329   3072
93  45329   3264
94  45329   3072
95  45329   3264
96  45329   0
97  45329   192
98  45329   0
99  45329   192
100 45329   0
101 45329   192
102 45329   0
103 45329   192
104 45329   0
105 45329   192
106 45329   0
107 45329   192
108 45329   0
109 45329   192
110 45329   0
111 45329   192
112 45329   3072
113 45329   3264
114 45329   3072
115 45329   3264
116 45329   3072
117 45329   3264
118 45329   3072
119 45329   3264
120 45329   3072
121 45329   3264
122 45329   3072
123 45329   3264
124 45329   3072
125 45329   3264
126 45329   3072
127 45329   3264
128 45329   0
129 45329   192
130 45329   0
131 45329   192
132 45329   0
133 45329   192
134 45329   0
135 45329   192
136 45329   0
137 45329   192
138 45329   0
139 45329   192
140 45329   0
141 45329   192
142 45329   0
143 45329   192
144 45329   3072
145 45329   3264
146 45329   3072
147 45329   3264
148 45329   3072
149 45329   3264
150 45329   3072
151 45329   3264
152 45329   3072
153 45329   3264
154 45329   3072
155 45329   3264
156 45329   3072
157 45329   3264
158 45329   3072
159 45329   3264
160 45329   0
161 45329   192
162 45329   0
163 45329   192
164 45329   0
165 45329   192
166 45329   0
167 45329   192
168 45329   0
169 45329   192
170 45329   0
171 45329   192
172 45329   0
173 45329   192
174 45329   0
175 45329   192
176 45329   3072
177 45329   3264
178 45329   3072
179 45329   3264
180 45329   3072
181 45329   3264
182 45329   3072
183 45329   3264
184 45329   3072
185 45329   3264
186 45329   3072
187 45329   3264
188 45329   3072
189 45329   3264
190 45329   3072
191 45329   3264
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to make sense of what this line of code is actually doing?

Comment: What is `current_pixel_line` ? What is its definition?

Comment: @wildplasser I have edited to add this information but it is an int.

Comment: Whoever is voting to close - if you can guide as to how I could better present this I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: You must be using a compiler with a nonstandard extension.  For better or worse, binary constants like `0b111` are not part of Standard C.  But this may be part of your misunderstanding: binary `111` is 7.  It's *not* `0xb111`, i.e. 45329.

Comment: @SteveSummit OK I knew I had at least one fundamental misunderstanding about the code I was looking at.  The fact that this is binary 111 and not hex b111 is a pretty big misunderstanding thank you for correcting me.

Comment: On 8bit computers characters are typically in cells and you don't have enough video memory to store them pixel by pixel. What this piece of code does is it maps currently rendered pixel line to those pre-encoded cells. `0b111` is `7`. For each pixel line 0-191 bitwise and with 7 you find number of bank 0-7 (which line of character you draw). Then * 192 gives you offset where pixels of characters valid for current line start. Later `&character_row[3*(terminal_line[x] & 0x3F)];` gives you right character from that line.

Comment: @SteveSummit `0b` is gcc extension for binary constants (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants)

Comment: @DukeDougal printing character rows like this in format: pixel line, bank, offset in ROM should give you better idea:
`for (int i = 0; i < 192; i++) { printf("%d %d %d\n", i, (i & 0b111), (i & 0b111) * 192); }`